# Fixed joints for publishing transform frames using URDF

Tags: navigation, ubuntu, tf-broadcaster, ubuntu-precise, joint-state-publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have developed an URDF file and i am using the URDF file to publish the robot transforms. I have made all the joints fixed in the urdf.
Is that fine if i have fixed joints in URDF to publish transforms of continuous joints(wheels & casters) or i should make the wheels and caster joints as continuous joints for perfect operation.

Note: I don't want to simulate the URDF model with Gazebo. I just want the file to publish transforms and aid the operation of real robot.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/243931/fixed-joints-for-publishing-transform-frames-using-urdf/) by [Kishore Kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/20863/kishore-kumar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 173 on 2016-09-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Often you don't need to model the wheel and caster joints to use the URDF with the navigation stack. (They're useful for visualizing the robot, of course.) For example, for a differential-drive robot you need a single frame for the robot base, probably halfway between the two wheels, often called `base_link`. Then you need frames for each of your sensors, unless you are publishing distances relative to `base_link` instead. The wheel positions don't really matter – your odometry layer will usually publish the transform between the `odom` frame and the `base_link` frame.

The transforms from `base_link` to the sensor frames are usually published automatically by `robot_state_publisher` and `joint_state_publisher`. Movable joint transformations are handled the same way, but you have to publish the joint positions so that `joint_state_publisher` can determine the right transformations.

---

Originally posted by [Mark Rose](https://answers.ros.org/users/27558/mark-rose/) with karma: 1563 on 2016-09-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1